# How do i get permission to edit freedesktop.org.xml?

Tags: 14.04, flash

I'm relatively new to using Ubuntu and I just recently upgraded to 14.04 LTS and as of the upgrade I can no longer run locally saved .swf files in my browser.

I did some googling for the answer and came up with editing the line

```
<mime-type type="application/vnd.adobe.flash.movie">
```

in mime's freedesktop.org.xml file to

```
<mime-type type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
```

but attempting to do so tells me I do not have permission.

I'm aware that I need to edit the file as root, but I simply do not now how to do so.

Thank you in advance for taking the time to read this and hopefully answer my probably really dumb, and simple question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you might want to do is open up terminal with ctrl+alt+t and get to the folder where the file exists, for example:

```
cd /usr/tmp
```

Once you are in the folder, do

```
sudo chmod 777 insertfilenamehere
```

That gives you full permission to edit that file.
Next you can edit it, and save it without problems!

Profit!

Comment: Thatnk you for the help, now I just have one other problem. When attempting to save the modification I get told that it could not make a backup of the file. Upon hitting "Save anyway" it continues to say the same thing and won't save the document.

Comment: @Jason Ouch, exactly the same thing has happened to me today. I found an easy fix. open up terminal and do 

`cd Desktop`   

Next, you want to copy all the text from the original file by doing ctrl+a and then ctrl+c. From there, go back to your terminal, and type

   `sudo gedit filenamehere`   

Then paste the text with ctrl+v and save.
Once that's done, go back to terminal and type something like this:

    `sudo mv /home/usernamehere/Desktop/filenamehere /usr/tmp/filenamehere`    

(first one is the file on your desktop, second is the original file, it force-saves it.)

Profit!!!

Comment: Oops, my "enter" buttons were not put in to my comment, sorry it's a bit tedious to read :P